# NoClassDefFoundError eventhough class in in same folder

Tags: java, classpath

I executed a main class and got the following error and trace.

This is the console command:

> java -cp . net.sf.tinyPayroll.Main

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hsqldb.Trace
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at net.sf.tinyPayroll.dao.DBConnector.connectDataFile(DBConnector.java:88)
    at net.sf.tinyPayroll.dao.DBConnector.<init>(DBConnector.java:72)
    at net.sf.tinyPayroll.dao.DBConnector.getInstance(DBConnector.java:106)
    at net.sf.tinyPayroll.model.DataFile.<init>(DataFile.java:53)
    at net.sf.tinyPayroll.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

However, all the necessary classes are in the same folder.

Here is the file which is extracted and available in the same folder (the entire library is available in extracted form).

> find . -name Trace*

```
./org/hsqldb/Trace.class
./org/hsqldb/util/Traceable.class
```

Comment: Maybe wrong permissions?

Comment: What happens if you it like `java -cp "." ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nicolas has mentioned this doesn't mean that it cannot find the class `org.hsqldb.Trace` in your classpath, it means that the class could not be initialized for some reason.
I've checked the code (This might change based on version) http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.1/org/hsqldb/Trace.java
In the class it has some static block which do some processing. Most probably some of the resources are missing in your class path

Comment: When this app was bundled, build tool has extracted dependencies into the same Jar file. However, only .class files have been added. Resources folder is empty without any .properties files. One of these properties files is used in Trace.java

Comment: It is surprising that java didn't give a "nested exception"/"caused by" which would have been so useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception is:

> `NoClassDefFoundError`: **Could not initialize class `org.hsqldb.Trace`**

Which doesn't mean that it cannot find  the class `org.hsqldb.Trace` in your classpath, it means that **the class could not be initialized** for some reason.

It generally means that a `RuntimeException` was thrown while either trying to assign a value to a **static field** or while trying to execute some code in a **static block**.

For example we will get such issue in the next cases:

```
class Trace {

    static MyClass foo = MyClass.newInstance(); // If it fails while calling newInstance

    static {
        SomeClass.init(); // If it fails while calling SomeClass.init()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought there would be a caused by in that case. So, I thought it was something else. Ill check.